# Selenium testing with GeoLocate- FireFox keeps turning it off

Tags: firefox, selenium, geolocation, selenium-webdriver

I am running tests on a location-aware site.  I can tell Chrome or IE to always allow geo-locate for that one page, but Firefox always forgets once I close the browser.

Anyone else ever encounter this?

Answer (score 4):

The Selenium driver for Firefox seems to create [a new, anonymous profile with each run](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver) by default. Hence your settings won't persist, as they will be discarded together with the profile after a run.

You should:

- Set up your `FirefoxProfile` instance to use `.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing", true);` and `.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", true);`.
- or set up an existing profile with the either the above preferences or explicitly allow your site. Then set the `webdriver.firefox.profile` Java System property or use the `public FirefoxProfile(File profileDir)` constructor to use that existing profile.

Comment: The first point worked for me!
I did:
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing", true);
    profile.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", true);